# Class not found in project error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

The following is my code:

```
package student;
public class Student {
private String idNumber;
private int creditHoursEarned;
private int pointsEarned;

public Student(){
        this.idNumber = "9999";
        this.creditHoursEarned = 3;
        this.pointsEarned = 12;
}
        public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
}
public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
}
public int getCreditHoursEarned() {
        return creditHoursEarned;
}
public void setCreditHoursEarned(int creditHoursEarned) {
        this.creditHoursEarned = creditHoursEarned;
}
public int getPointsEarned() {
        return pointsEarned;
}
public void setPointsEarned(int pointsEarned) {
        this.pointsEarned = pointsEarned;
}
public double calculateGpa() {
        double gradePointAverage = (double)pointsEarned / creditHoursEarned;
        return gradePointAverage;
}
public String toString() {
        return "Student --"+
        "Id Number: " + idNumber+
        ", Credit Hours Earned: " + creditHoursEarned+
        ", Points Earned: " + pointsEarned;
}    
        }
```

When I try to run it in Netbeans IDE 7.4 I get and error:

`student.Student class wasn't found in Student project`

Comment: Show the main() method where you try to use this class. Also, beware that if your classes are in different packages you will have to use an import statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely to do with your packaging structure, either create a new package named `student` and save this class in it or try and remove `package student;` from the top of the file.

Comment: I tried removing the package student and the error is still present

Comment: Where are you using the `Student` class from?

Comment: This is the first in a series of three codes I am writing for a project and I am using Netbeans

Comment: Ah, so you've been given this code, and you're trying to run it? In which case, you've probably not set up the project correctly.

Comment: student.Student class wasn't found in Student project

Comment: When I run the Clean and Build function it compiles without error

Comment: Try creating a new project, with a new package named `student` and a new class named `Student`, and then past that code into the class.

Comment: I assume it's working now? I think the Clean and Build function automatically sorts out the incorrect packaging structure.

Comment: It didn't and I am at a complete loss

Comment: Have you created the project again from scratch, as suggested above? By doing that I was able to get your class working in Netbeans.

Comment: Yes I actually did it twice. Deleting it both times. I tried renamine the main class through properties, still same error.

Comment: Right click on the `Source Packages` and select `new Java Package...`, name this `student`, right click on that package and click `new Java Class...`, inside of that class paste your code.